# Encapsulate udp traffic info tcp with on-disk buffering

Tags: tcp, buffer, netflow, socat

My ipfix flow receiver supports only udp (can't be replaced), which is not resistant to network failures and then I'm loosing flow data. To improve this I'm thinking about using socat, mkfifo between flow exporter and flow receiver. But I dont know, how to save data to disk on exporter side when network is down and resend when back online. Default linux pipes are 1MB, but I need for example 1GB buffer.

How can I do this?

Thank you.